# Fonts for mathematical metalanguage?

Tags: fonts

I want to distinguish formulas of the metalanguage from formulas of the object language in a mathematical text. What may be good practices to abide by, for reasons of style and stability?

Comment: font choice isn't clearly on topic here but, usually, or at least often, you choose a more stylised font for the meta language, so it depends how many fonts you use at the base.  you could use roman then italic, or if the base is already using math italic, meta could use calligraphic or script  or (since it's 21st century) use black for the base language and green for the meta language or .....

Comment: I voted @DavidCarlisle's comment since I agree that the choice isn't clearly on topic here. Your best bet is to look around the literature and see what other people use. For accessibility however I would caution **against using color** as the sole distinguishing feature.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for the advices. There should be distinguishing features beside color.

Comment: Iso ISO 80000—which, before egreg says anything, is not universally adopted or regarded as correct—suggests sans-serif fonts for names that are not mathematical objects. it’s also traditional to use typewriter fonts for code listings.

Comment: @Davislor OK It seems to me that technical vocabulary in the other natural sciences, and beyond, also rely heavily upon the use of symbols not in the Latin alphabet. Are there sans serif fonts for Greek, and for mathematical and logical symbols, which I make heavily use of?

Comment: @Sapiens Yes. For example, CMU Sans Serif, New Computer Modern Sans, Libertinus Sans, Fira Sans and TeX Gyre Heros. In `unicode-math`, you can enable any of them as a math alphabet with `\setmathsf` or `\setmathfontface`.